# Converting coordinate tuple information to numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have results from a finite element program that give various measures of interest (e.g., temperature, density, pressure) at regularly-spaced grid locations in three-dimensional space.

Values are equally spaced along each coordinate, but this spacing may be different for the different coordinates. For example,

```
x1 = [0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1.0]      (a total of NX1 pts) 
x2 = [0, 0.5, 1.0, ..., 20]       (a total of NX2 pts) 
x3 = [0, 0.2, 0.4, ..., 15]       (a total of NX3 pts)
```

The results output from the software are in the following form:

```
x1_1, x2_1, x3_1, f_x, g_x, h_x
x1_1, x2_1, x3_2, f_x, g_x, h_x
x1_1, x2_1, x3_3, f_x, g_x, h_x
...
x1_1, x2_2, x3_1, f_x, g_x, h_x
x1_1, x2_2, x3_2, f_x, g_x, h_x
x1_1, x2_2, x3_3, f_x, g_x, h_x
...
x1_2, x2_1, x3_1, f_x, g_x, h_x
x1_2, x2_1, x3_2, f_x, g_x, h_x
x1_2, x2_1, x3_3, f_x, g_x, h_x
...
```

where the f_x, g_x, h_x are the measures of interest at the particular grid point.

I would like to convert the above data format and obtain (NX1 x NX2 x NX3) numpy arrays for f, g, and h.

Some of the results sets are fairly large (80 x 120 x 100).

Does anyone have any hints for doing this conversion in an efficient manner?

Comment: Is there a way you can provide some small sample data in the form of Python code to illustrate your problem? I'm not sure I understand your output format and what you mean when you say you want arrays "for" f, g and h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you read your whole array into memory as an array `data` of shape `(Nx1 * Nx2 * Nx3, 6)`.

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=float, delimiter=',')
```

If, as your, example suggests, the points are generated in lexicographical order, you only need to grab the columns to `f`, `g` and `h` and reshape them:

```
f = data[:, 3].reshape(Nx1, Nx2, Nx3)
g = data[:, 4].reshape(Nx1, Nx2, Nx3)
h = data[:, 5].reshape(Nx1, Nx2, Nx3)
```

If you need to figure out what `Nx1`, `Nx2` and `Nx3` are, you can use `np.unique`:

```
Nx1 = np.unique(data[:, 0]).shape[0]
Nx2 = np.unique(data[:, 1]).shape[0]
Nx3 = np.unique(data[:, 2]).shape[0]
```

A more robust solution in case the order of the points is not guaranteed, would be to use `np.unique` to extract indices to the grid values:

```
Nx1, idx1 = np.unique(data[:, 0], return_inverse=True)
Nx1 = Nx1.shape[0]
Nx2, idx2 = np.unique(data[:, 1], return_inverse=True)
Nx2 = Nx2.shape[1]
Nx3, idx3 = np.unique(data[:, 2], return_inverse=True)
Nx3 = Nx3.shape[0]

f = np.empty((Nx1, Nx2, Nx3))
f[idx1, idx2, idx3] = data[:, 3]
g = np.empty((Nx1, Nx2, Nx3))
g[idx1, idx2, idx3] = data[:, 4]
h = np.empty((Nx1, Nx2, Nx3))
h[idx1, idx2, idx3] = data[:, 5]
```

This will create new arrays for `f`, `g` and `h`, not views into the original `data` array, so it will use more memory.

And of course instead of my ugly code above repeating everything three times, you should use a loop, or a list comprehension!

Comment: Don't all the references to `data[n]` give the `n`th row, not column?  I should think most of them should be replaced with `data[:,n]`

Comment: @askewchan I've already edited, but, for simplicity, it may be better to simply set `unpack=True` in the call to `np.loadtxt`, which is equivalent to doing `data = data.T`, and leave the code as it was.

Comment: Thank you for the great ideas! I now have a working and flexible solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the entire file no matter what, so why not just initialize the array and feed in the values?

The tricky part is that if you want an array with shape `(NX1,NX2,NX3)`, but if your `x1,x2,x3` values are `float`s, then you have to index your array somehow.  Perhaps a data structure exists for this but you could usome something like

```
def xyz_index((x,y,z),(n1,n2,n3)):
    """ return integer indices for x,y,z position
        given a constant step """
    return tuple(map(int,[x/n1,y/n2,z/n3]))

import numpy as np
NX1,NX2,NX3 =  (80, 120, 100)
ns = n1, n2, n3 =   (.1,.5,.2)
x1, x2, x3 = np.arange(0,1+n1,n1), np.arange(0,20+n2,n2), np.arange(0,15+n3,n3),

data = np.empty((NX1,NX2,NX3),dtype=[('f',float),('g',float),('h',float)])
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        x,y,z,f,g,h = map(float,line.split(', '))
        data[xyz_index((x,y,z),ns)] = (f,g,h)
```

Then you can access your data as follows:

For the `h`-value at point `x1,x2,x3 = .2, .5, 0.`, use

```
data[xyz_index((.2,.5,0),ns)]['h']
```

Without the `['h']`, this would return an `(f,g,h)` tuple with the `dtype` above.

Without the index, it will return an `(NX1,NX2,NX3)` array of all the `h`-values.

---

Now that I look at it, if `n1, n2, n3` are always the same you might want to define them *inside* your `xyz_index` function so then you wouldn't have to pass the `ns` in every time:

```
data[xyz_index(.2,.5,0)]['h']
```